# How to check the number of outliers in my data?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, outliers, robust

I have multivariate data and want to check for outliers. I guess there are both outliers in the predictor variables and the dependent variable. 
My idea was to fit robust regression methods after observing how many outliers there are. For variable selection I want to use robust versions of the AIC, but this is only useful if I know the number of outliers.

The data type is the following:
There are 30 predictors (some will be removed). 1 with continuous values between 0 and 5 and the rest with discrete values of type 0/1 or range 1 up to 8. The variables may be dependent.
I would like to make the data file available but I don't know how I put a csv-file in a question here (does anybody know how this works?).

Which methods are useful to check for outliers here?

Comment: Robust regression is (arguably) intended to make outlier identification unnecessary, or equivalently to allow that in its wake. The practice is a little more complicated as flavours of robust regression work in slightly or even very different ways. We need to see your data but it sounds like a very well-behaved dataset so that you are likely to be disappointed in your search for outliers. But there are many threads here on outliers: did you read around before posting? There really isn't a way to identify outliers that is simple and universal; that depends on your model.

Comment: My predictors describe complexity levels and the dependent variable is the number of days that are needed to test a car (based on its complexity). I wanted to use robust methods because in the historical data there are for example some cars which had problems in the testing procedure (and need more than usual...). So I think I need robust methods which are not much influenced by this. I used in R the lmRob.S function which gives also robust weights. I think the variable with low weight can be interpreted as an outlier?

Comment: As I said I don't know how to put the file of the data into the question...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't comment on particular R functions; I use R about once per year. The built-in editor here has many icons, including those for attachments.